# Display Webdis response in browser

Tags: jquery, redis

I am trying to display Redis data in the browser using Webdis and jQuery.  Redis and Webdis are working correctly from the command line (using curl), but I cannot get the data to display in the browser. Webdis responds with JSON and the curl response is **{"GET":"103"}**.  Anyone know the problem?  Suggestions for improving any of this are welcome.  Thanks!

The code is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- load JQuery from Google API -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <!-- This is the jQuery template for the JSON returned by Webdis -->
<script id="webdisTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <li>${GET}</li>

</script>

<!-- jQuery Ajax request through Webdis that feeds the Redis data into the template -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:7379/GET/value",
            data: "format=json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#webdisTemplate").tmpl(data.items).appendTo("#placeholder");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
<title>Webdis Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Value:</h4>
    <ul id="placeholder"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass "format=json" to you server method? If not, the "data:" property represents parameters you want to pass and must be defined by the server method.

Comment: That does look rather wrong. Post your PRECISE curl command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a little late but I guess it can be useful to other people to. 
I used two machines so if there was any CORS problem it should rise, I didn't 
had any problem with it though. My snippet snows how to get data though $.ajax,
if you still face the problem let me know in order to expand the answer.

In your js code:

```
var key = 123;

$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com:7379",
  data: "GET/" + key,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) { 
    $("outputArea").html(data.GET);
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log("error", err);
  });

$("#outputArea").html(data.GET);
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of Webdis. I am pretty sure @bmargulies is right, this looks like a CORS issue.
Webdis does include a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, but it might not be enough.

I have opened [a ticket on the github project to keep track of this issue](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis/issues/39). I'll have a look at it today.

Cheers,

Nicolas

**(edit)**

The request actually works fine, even when executed for a separate domain. Webdis includes CORS headers, namely `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Allow: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS`.

That said, the template line doesn't work for me:

```
$("#webdisTemplate").tmpl(data.items).appendTo("#placeholder");
```

I get the following error message in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tmpl'
```

If I use `console.log` to print `data`, I can see the response object as expected.

I can confirm that it works in both Chromium 15 and Firefox 8.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas.  Webdis is working and responding correctly.  The problem is somewhere else.  By the way, Webdis is really great - thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question is not for someone here to guess the problem by reading your code and imagining your server configuration, but rather for you to use debugging tools.

If, for example, you use the Chrome developer tools, the network view will show you exactly what ends up going from the browser to the service, and what comes back.

You might even just see an explanatory Javascript exception.

I strongly suspect that you are suffering from CORS, and that the browser is refusing to let you do this because this web page is not being served from http://127.0.0.1:7379.